# How do I determine the Id for the title in jpeg when using System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, metadata, jpeg, exif

So far I created a simple upload function, download function and the a class to change file properties, but right now how do I determine the Id for the attributes or properties I want to change eg. Title, Author, Subject, etc. Currently I'm using `System.Drawing.Imaging`.dll for my library.

This is how far I got with my `ChangeFileProperties` class:

```
public class ChangeFileProperties
{ 
    public void ChangeFileAuthor(string FilePath)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FilePath);

        //??
        PropertyItem propitem = image.GetPropertyItem(0x0320);
        //??
        propitem.Id = 0x0321;
        propitem.Len = propitem.Value.Length;
        propitem.Type = 1;
        propitem.Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyImageInfo");
        image.SetPropertyItem(propitem);


        image.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\test.jpeg");
    }
}
```

So right now, there no error in the codes but when I run the webpage, the errors pop up on the `??` comment part, the errors said

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Property cannot be found.

It seems the Id is wrong, so how do I know what Id is it for each attributes.

Comment: It pops up errors....so what errors?

Comment: @DavidG I have edited my post, the errors is now stated there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [`Image.PropertyItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyitems(v=vs.110).aspx) collection, you can get all the properties and loop through them:

```
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\wired\Pictures\1496422850103.jpeg");

foreach (var prop in image.PropertyItems)
{
    var id = prop.Id;
    //etc
}
```

Comment: Do I need to display them in order to know the id for each attributes?

Comment: it's up to you what you do with them.

Comment: hmm...ok I'll see what I can do with it. Thanks for your answer mate.

Comment: Eh, could you tell me how do I output the id cause I'm stuck there as I don't know how to do it, due to the fat I'm not familiar with c#